# Setting an document.element's x position

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is when the website loads up, it takes the `window.innerWidth` value and uses it along with the element's width to center the element horizontally.

```
x = (window.innerWidth - element's width) / 2
```

However, I can't find the right variables to trigger the command. I use the `document.getElementById` to get the element. But without knowing the properties/variables, I can't get the code to work.

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I like to use jQuery when measuring elements in javascript as it handles all the cross-browser nuances for you. element.width(); works every time.

Comment: @jeremy Your approach is much similar to that of making an application but in designing a webpage you can simply do such things by using simpler code of `CSS` that doesn't need much of a mathematical expression as you are using here. Even you can implement the `CSS` code with `JavaScript` in a much similar way. Check my answer and try it.

Comment: You could have tried to google it.

Comment: I have tried researching it but I couldn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To center an element horizontally, use this CSS:

```css
#yourElement {margin:0 auto}
```

This will work even if the window size changes ;)

Comment: In that case you'd use `left:0;right:0;width:something` and it will center for you.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Could've sworn I've seen it somewhere before. Well, in any case, `left:50%;margin-left:-100px;width:200px;` works.

Comment: I'd just use the table layout hack. `display:table` on the parent, `table-cell` on child, and then `text-align:center` to center.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol adding `margin: auto;` with the `left` and `right` centered it:  http://jsfiddle.net/r5qTP/1/

Comment: Ah, that's it. Knew I was missing something XD

Answer (score 0):

use the following style definition to make it aligned center by default-

```
style="text-align:center"
```

But as per what you are asking I can suggest something like the following-

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('div1').style.textAlign='center';">
    <div id='div1'>
        content
    </div>
</body>
```

Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn5u6/)**

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. I don't understand why this isn't work. It makes no sense. It just doesn't do anything. The content box appears but it appears in the top-left corner as it would a blank document.

Comment: I tried the fiddle link and it definitely makes the text centered. But I also want the background, box. Everything in that div centered.

Answer (score 0):

try this (note that the resize event fires automatically, once, on browser load):

```
var viewWindow =  $(window);
// bind a resize event listener on the Window
viewWindow.bind('resize', function () {
   // get the element
   var kWindow = jQuery('#someDiv');
   // compute and set the element's left and top css properties according to the new browser size
   kWindow.css({
      left: viewWindow.scrollLeft() + Math.max(0, (viewWindow.width() - kWindow.width()) / 2),
      top: viewWindow.scrollTop() + Math.max(0, (viewWindow.height() - kWindow.height()) / 2)
   });
});
```